# Объявление структуры С++ с typedef

Tags: c++, c

Постоянно вижу в различных учебниках такой синтаксис объявления структур

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Foo;
```

Скажите, чем такой синтаксис отличается от банального?

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В си типы структур и другие типы существуют в "разных пространствах имен". То есть, в си вполне можно написать так

```
struct data {
    int foo;
};

typedef int data;

void foo()
{
    struct data d1;
    data d2;
}
```

здесь и структура и тип синоним int имеют одинаковое имя. И это работает и компилируется. А уже в с++ - нет. Потому что в c типы находятся как бы в разных "таблицах".

Что бы тип структуры был доступен и в "основном списке", нужно писать typedef. Но потом кто то придумал такой красивый синтаксис, так как писать постоянно struct надоело.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш вопрос помечен тэгом [C++]. Но первый вариант объявления не несет практически никакой самостоятельной ценности в С++ коде. Первый вариант объявления часто применяется в С коде, но не в С++ коде.

Первый вариант объявления может использоваться в качестве "общего знаменателя" в кросс-компилируемых заголовочных файлах, т.е. в заголовочных файлах, которые должны компилироваться как в С коде, так и в С++ коде. После такого объявления как в С коде, так и в С++ коде можно будет ссылаться на данный тип через его "короткое" имя `Foo`.

В языке С++ такие объявления (объявляющие typedef-имя `Foo` в качестве псевдонима для уже существующего класса с точно таким же именем `Foo`) поддерживаются именно для обратной совместимости с языком С в кросс-компилируем коде.

Answer (score 3):

С стиль:

```
 typedef struct Foo {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } Foo;
```

без typedef нужно будет писать `struct Foo foo;`

Кстати, в С чтобы объявить указатель на Foo нужно использовать`struct Foo*`

```
     typedef struct Foo {
                ...
                struct Foo*foo;
            } Foo;
```

С++ стиль:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Тем, что при банальном синтаксисе везде надо тянуть слово `struct`, типа

```
void func(struct Foo* f);
```

а при небанальном достаточно

```
void func(Foo* f);
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*